# How to call a token directly from the WYSIWYG editor?

Tags: nodes, tokens

I wish to call a token directly from the WYSIWYG text editor of a node of a certain content type.

For example, I wish to call the token `[current-page:title]` (node `H1` tag) from the edit page.

So, for example for a node named "Tulip (Tulipus)":

### Input

> `The term [current-page:title] [plural: Tulipa] is used to describe a flower of the family Liliaceae.`

### Output

> The term Tulip (Tulipus) [plural: Tulipa] is used to describe a flower of the family Liliaceae.

How can this be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll want the [Token Filter](https://www.drupal.org/project/token_filter) module.

As the module's page says, you need to make sure you have the right context for the tokens you want to use; if the context isn't available, token replacement will fail silently.

Also note that [it's not yet ready for CKEditor 5.](https://www.drupal.org/project/token_filter/issues/3262052)

Comment: Hello Patrick and thank you. I have read in the module's page but it isn't clear to me what the word "context" means here, is it the node versus block issue detailed there? I plan to use it only for nodes.

Comment: Should using "token filter" as an input filter interfere with some HTML parsing?

Comment: May I add that the documentation page lacks clear data in these regards as well: https://www.drupal.org/docs/contributed-modules/token-filter

Comment: Tokens are usually linked to an entity, so for such tokens, the entity is the context.  If you use a token when it would not be available, it will fail.  Drupal usually gives you a widget to show the available tokens, but Token Filter d module does not have this; you will have to either use tokens that you know are safe or proceed carefully by trial and error.

Comment: Oh, as I figure now, the only token I am going to use is `[current-page:title]` within nodes.